# SQL- GROUP BY with CASE

Tags: sql, oracle19c

I have a query which is

```
Select FinalGradeStudent from grade
```

and it brings me the following column

| FinalGradeStudent |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 2 |
| 5 |
| 2 |
| 2 |
| 0 |
| 2 |
| 4 |

n grades... and I want something similar to this, to see the number of students who passed and failed the subject

| performance | Estudents |
| --- | --- |
| Passed | 3 |
| Failed | 5 |

the query I have done is the following

```
SELECT CASE WHEN FinalGradeStudent >= 3 THEN 'Passed' ELSE 'Failed' END Performance, COUNT(*) Estudents 
from Grade GROUP BY FinalGradeStudent
```

but my result is the following

| Performance | Estudents |
| --- | --- |
| Passed | 2 |
| Failed | 4 |
| Passed | 1 |
| Failed | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is fine, but the `CASE` expression needs to appear in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN FinalGradeStudent >= 3 THEN 'Passed' ELSE 'Failed' END Performance,
    COUNT(*) Estudents
FROM Grade
GROUP BY
    CASE WHEN FinalGradeStudent >= 3 THEN 'Passed' ELSE 'Failed' END;
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I did not know that after the group by the case could be made. thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply first create a temporary table with `case` and then do a group by query on that.

```
CREATE TABLE st (
  marks int
);

insert into st values(5);
insert into st values(2);
insert into st values(5);
insert into st values(2);
insert into st values(2);
insert into st values(0);
insert into st values(2);
insert into st values(4);
insert into st values(3);

-- QUERY
select sta.status as performance, count(*) as Estudents from (
  select case
    when marks>3 then 'PASSED'
    else 'FAILED'
    end as status
  from st) sta
group by sta.status;
```